# Cron service up but apparently not working

Tags: cron

I'm trying cron in a Ubuntu VPS with a minimal install, so I had to run `apt-get install cron`. However, say I run `crontab -e` and add (as root) the following line:

```
* * * * * date >> /root/datelog
```

I get the success notification:

```
crontab: installing new crontab
```

but **`/root/datelog` is never created**. If I try `start cron` I get:

```
start: Job is already running: cron
```

On the other hand, `ps` doesn't yield anything:

```
# ps -ef|grep cron
root      3087 10498  0 Mar17 pts/24   00:00:00 grep --color=auto cron
root     29081  7863  0 Mar13 pts/8    00:00:00 man crontab
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Edit: Following ImaginaryRobots' suggestion, I have modified my crontab as follows... to no avail.

```
* * * * * date >> /root/datelog
* * * * * date >> /tmp/datelog
* * * * * /bin/date >> /root/bindatelog
* * * * * /bin/date >> /tmp/bindatelog
```

I.e., no such files appear either in `/root` or in `/tmp`.

Edit 2: Maybe I should mention that Ubuntu 12.04 (or at least this VPS) is giving me what I consider to be a well-known bug upon `apt-get upgrade`:

```
mount: permission denied
dpkg: error processing initscripts (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initscripts
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Packages install apparently with no problems. But this may be affecting the behavior of the system after all...

Comment: Are you installing that cron as root? It may be a permission issue with the file you are trying to create.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying everything as root. (Have a bad tendency in that sense...)

Comment: can you paste the output of the following?  pgrep 'cron'

Comment: There is nothing to paste, unfortunately: the command does not grep anything... Kindly refer to my second edit; maybe it has some bearing on all of this.

Comment: Reinstall cron.

Answer (score 1):

It's good practice to list the full path for anything being called from a cron job, since the environment variables are not always the same as they are for your user.  Additionally, since you are trying to debug things, try writing to the /tmp/ directory instead.   Try the following line:

```
* * * * * /bin/date >> /tmp/datelog
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion (can't upvote yet...). However, this doesn't do it for me. It's really puzzling, since I recall something like this working under Debian. Please refer to my edit.